# How to use the Func<Task<T>> Syntax?

Tags: c#

I found this class in another answer [Best way in .NET to manage queue of tasks on a separate (single) thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691679/best-way-in-net-to-manage-queue-of-tasks-on-a-separate-single-thread).

I wanted to try it out, but the syntax is a bit strange to me.  Trying to just kick off a dummy task that returns a single int.  I can't get this to compile, not sure what the syntax problem is.

```
        m_TaskQueue.Enqueue<int>(
                () => { return 1; }
            );
```

Compiler error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type `System.Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<int>>` because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Class from other answer:

```
public class TaskQueue
{
    private SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    public TaskQueue()
    {
        semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    }

    public async Task<T> Enqueue<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskGenerator)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
    public async Task Enqueue(Func<Task> taskGenerator)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's  the error compiler saying?

Comment: You are passing `Func<int>` and **not** `Func<Task<int>>`

Comment: Side note: code you've found *does not* schedule tasks on separate thread, so adding synchronous tasks is mostly pointless as frequently they'll run synchronously on the current thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add to the other answers which suggest using `Task.FromResult` to create a task, you could also use an async lambda expression - this would be useful if you want to use `await` within the body of the lambda expression:

```
m_TaskQueue.Enqueue<int>(
    async () => { 
        await Task.Delay(1000); // For example
        return 1;
    }
);
```

Comment: So somehow adding an async/await to the lambda turns it from a `Func<int>` to a `Func<Task<int>>`?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I think  `async` lambdas is not workaround, but actually intended way to call this queuing code - there is really not much value to schedule synchronous operation to queue that will run it synchronously on the same thread  in most cases.

Comment: @user17753: @user17753: Yup - just like adding `async` to a method declaration means that it has to have a return type of `Task<int>` instead of `int` (but within the method, you still return an `int`...) Note that you don't *have* to `await` anything there, although you'll get a warning if you don't - it's the `async` contextual keyword which is important here.

Comment: Would something like `async () => { return await Task.Run( () => { return myInt; });` Make sense as well?  Where I would do a bunch of stuff before returning myInt (perhaps slow I/O etc.).

Comment: @user17753: Why would you do that? Instead of using `Task.Run`, just use asynchronous IO calls within the lambda expression.

Comment: OK I got it now. Thanks.  Makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

As the error is trying to tell you, you need a function that returns a `Task<T>`.

You can use `Task.FromResult(1)` to create one.