# Problems scheduling/starting task on a custom TaskScheduler, which will complete execution on said Scheduler

Tags: c#, asynchronous, .net-core, async-await, task-parallel-library

The work I'm trying to schedule is using the `await` keyword, hence the work itself is of type `async Task`.

I can't use `Task.Factory.StartNew`, even when I pass my scheduler, because it will consider the task "done" when it hits the first await of the work, making it leave the scheduler and continuing on the default scheduler.

I can't use `var a = new Task(DoWork....); a.Start(myScheduler)`, because I'd be using an `async void` method, and we know the pitfalls to that.

I can't use `Task.Run()`, because it doesn't allow you to change the scheduler on which the task will be scheduled to launch.

If I can't use any of that, how will I achieve my goal, which is to schedule my async Work, which has to complete execution on the scheduler it was initially started on?

Comment: It is not possible to throttle async operations with the `TaskScheduler` class. You can see an experiment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428604/how-to-run-a-task-on-a-custom-taskscheduler-using-await/57702536#57702536), where I tried (and failed) to do just that. To throttle async operations you need a `SemaphoreSlim`, or to create the desired number of worker tasks to process your workload, or use the TPL Dataflow library that is async-friendly and allows to define the level of concurrency by setting the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` option.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias when you say "create desired number of worker tasks" you mean long-running tasks which will do the work as it comes?

Is there an example of Dataflow library usage, with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`? First time hearing about it.

Comment: Yes, long running tasks that each one creates and awaits one async operation at a time. This is how the TPL Dataflow library works internally (I think). You can see an example of this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56862796/11178549). For an example of using the TPL Dataflow library with async code and `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59574072/11178549).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias That's so cool! I've decided to go with the semaphoreSlim approach, although I think performance would be slightly better if I used the action block, simply because I won't be starting X tasks, which would asynchronously wait for the semaphore to be released, versus starting a single task (if `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` = 1) and when that task completes - start the next one? Is that how it works? Any idea if the next started task will be based on `TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness`? Meaning the sooner it was scheduled, the more likely for it to be executed?

Comment: Creating a task with `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync` has minimal overhead, and you shouldn't observe any noticeable difference unless your workload has several million items. About the option `TaskCreationOptions.PreferFairness` I have never used it personally. I wouldn't expect it to make any difference though, but you could experiment with it if squeezing some milliseconds is important in your case. :-)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias is it a problem if I have an `ActionBlock<>` that will live throughout the whole application's lifespan, queuing/ingesting constantly work which is being handled when appropriate? Is `ActionBlock<>` made in mind with these things, or will I be abusing a feature? (Long-lived instance, never calling `ActionBlock<>.Complete()` )

Comment: No, there should be no problem with using an `ActionBlock` for years. The Dataflow blocks are not known to leak resources. The only consideration is the size of its input queue. If you let it unbounded, and it constantly receives more messages than it can process, the queue will grow larger and larger, and will eventually explode with an `OutOfMemory` exception. For this reason it is a good idea to use the `BoundedCapacity` option when you create the block. If you use this option, be careful to feed the block with `SendAsync` instead of `Post`, otherwise you may lose messages.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I've opened a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62016856/avoiding-use-of-actionblocktinput-post-when-postdataflowblockoptions-boundedca) in regards to your last comment. Feel free to answer there. I'd love to reward some bounty points for all the helpful information you've covered here!

Comment: OK, I'll take a look at that question later. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, be aware that the `TaskScheduler` only applies to *executing* tasks. So when using an `async` delegate, the `TaskScheduler` will only be used in-between `await` points; when the `async` code is (asynchronously) waiting in an `await`, then there is no code "in" that scheduler. For some schedulers this isn't a problem, but it is a problem with schedulers like `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair` because the code is not "in" the scheduler during an `await`.

If your `TaskScheduler` will work as expected with `async` code, then you can create a task running on it by calling `Task.Factory.StartNew` and passing your `TaskScheduler`. This will return a `Task<Task>` or `Task<Task<T>>` since `StartNew` doesn't understand `async` code; you can call `Unwrap()` on that value to get a "normal" asynchronous `Task`/`Task<T>`.

Personally, I prefer creating your own `TaskFactory` instance with your own `TaskScheduler` (and other options), and then call that `StartNew` with `Unwrap`. E.g:

```
var factory = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
    TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach, myTaskScheduler);
var task = factory.StartNew(() => MyCodeAsync()).Unwrap();
```

If desired, I have written some [`Run` overloads for `TaskFactory`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/db32fd5db0d1051e867b36ae039ea13d2c36eb91/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskFactoryExtensions.cs) that make the `TaskFactory` usage look more like `Task.Run`:

```
// Equivalent to the above code
var factory = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.DenyChildAttach,
    TaskContinuationOptions.DenyChildAttach, myTaskScheduler);
var task = factory.Run(() => MyCodeAsync());
```

Comment: The `TaskScheduler` I'm using is indeed coming from `ConcurrentExclusiveSchedulerPair`. Is there a possible work-around to the issues you've outlined, or my only alternative is to somehow avoid all the `awaits` inside? It's an honor to have you answer my question.

Comment: I'd say the best solution is to replace the entire `TaskScheduler` with appropriately-placed `SemaphoreSlim` locks within the code. If that's too much work, then you'd need to avoid `async`/`await` in any code running on that `TaskScheduler`.