# C# Queue a Task returning the result when it will be executed from the queue

Tags: c#, multithreading, queue, singleton, task

I have the following structure:

```
 //function called from Node.js
 public Task<object> NodeCall (IDictionary<string, object> payload) {
     Func<object, Task<object>> changed = (Func<object, Task<object>>) payload["changed"];

     return Task.Run (async () => await OnQuery (payload["request"], changed));
 }

public async Task<object> OnQuery (dynamic request, dynamic payload = null) {
    var result = new QueryCallback ();
    //...code...
    return result
}
```

In the code of "OnQuery" I should call a function of a singleton class and I need to queue the calls. The problem is that queuing I can't handle the thread response and awaiting the result the task send the reply.

My final result would be: put the task in the queue and when the singleton dequeue my task and finish the target function I return the result. 
In the while the OnQuery task should wait without returning anything.

Can someone help me with that?

Thanks

**Edit 1**
Servy signed as possible duplicate of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25691829/4991755) but I am not sure it can handle the result... If is it the right way can someone make a better sample please? It's not clear for me

Comment: Which calls do you need to queue exactly?

Comment: @MindSwipe What do u mean? OnQuery Task should be in the queue awaiting it will be removed from queue and executed and only next return the result. But I also consider others approachs

Answer (score -1):

You can use `SemaphoreSlim` as noted in the [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691679/best-way-in-net-to-manage-queue-of-tasks-on-a-separate-single-thread):

```
private readonly SemaphoreSlim _mutex = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
public async Task<object> OnQuery (dynamic request, dynamic payload = null)
{
  await _mutex.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    var result = new QueryCallback ();
    //...code...
    return result
  }
  finally
  {
    _mutex.Release();
  }
}
```

Side note: this is not technically a *queue*, since strict FIFO order isn't guaranteed. It is, however, a way to enforce exclusive access to a shared resource, and this should suffice for what you need.