Enqueue tasks inside event handlers
I have a WPF application and a long process running on a separate thread.
The process is firing events here and then. There are many events, each one can be fired one or more times.
The interface has the event handlers which are doing some stuff (sometime async!).
Here an example.
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Value { get; }
    public MyEventArgs(int value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}

public class LongJobWorker()
{
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> Event1;
    public event EventHandler<MyEventArgs> Event2;
    public async Task DoSomething()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            Event1?.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs(i));
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            Event2?.Invoke(this, new MyEventArgs(i));
        }
    }

}

public class Presenter()
{
    LongJobWorker m_worker;
    public Presenter()
    {
        var m_worker = new LongJobWorker();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        m_worker.Event1 += worker_Event1;
        m_worker.Event2 += worker_Event2;
        _ = Task.Run(async () => await m_worker.DoSomething());
    }

    private async void worker_Event1(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
    {
        // update something in interface like put some text into a label
        UpdateSomethingInUI(e.Value);

        // do something async like write a file
        await WriteSomethingOnFile(e.Value);
    }

    private async void worker_Event2(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
    {
        // update something in interface like put some text into a label
        UpdateSomethingElseInUI(e.Value);

        // do something async like write a file
        await WriteSomethingElseOnFile(e.Value);
    }
}

I want to enqueue the operations inside event handlers in such way:

event handlers operations do not run in parallel but are serialized FIFO. The first fired event executes, the the second, etc.
event handler operations do not start before operations of another handler are completed (I want to wait the end of task).

Basing on the code above, operations are exectuted in this way:

UpdateSomethingInUI(0)
WriteSomethingOnFile(0)
UpdateSomethingElseInUI(0)
WriteSomethingElseOnFile(0)
UpdateSomethingInUI(1)
WriteSomethingOnFile(1)
UpdateSomethingElseInUI(1)
WriteSomethingElseOnFile(1)
etc...

Possibly I want to get rid of async void. I know that for event handlers is acceptable but if there is a way to remove it, I will apreciate.

Have you considered switching to IProgress<T> / Progress<T> instead of using Events?

Uahhh ... _ = Task.Run(async () => await m_worker.DoSomething()); - that's asking for trouble. Why not go async all the way?

DoSomething is CPU bound so I need to call it on a separate thread.

@MaestroX Then it shouldn't return a Task, and you shouldn't be using Task.Delay as a stand in for that work.  Everything about what you've shown indicates it's asynchronous.

DoSomething sometime may have also a small component of async operation (i.e. networking). That's why I made it async.

Then it should be actually asynchronous.  If it has long running CPU bound work to do it should itself use Task.Run to perform that work to ensure that the calling method is not blocked.

And then it should be used async. All the way up.

Ok, that's not a very big deal: I can refactorize. But, if I'm not wrong, this does not solve the problem of event handler serialization.

What are the constraints? Are you allowed to make changes to the LongJobWorker class, or it should be kept as is?

There are almost no technical constraints. I can modify everything because the application is mine.
What interests me is that the events are handled in sequence: one after the other, in the order in which they were fired and without overlap.
It matters little if the interface finishes queuing events after the LongJobWorker has finished. What matters is that they are queued in the right order.

This use case seems to be solved by using the AsyncAutoResetEvent primitive that Stephen Toub built in this excellent blog post.
The class looks like this (I've added a ctor for the initial state which we'll need to be true):
public class AsyncAutoResetEvent
{
    private readonly static Task s_completed = Task.FromResult(true);
    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> m_waits = new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
    private bool m_signaled;

    public AsyncAutoResetEvent(bool initialState) {
        m_signaled = initialState;
    }

    public Task WaitAsync() {
        lock (m_waits) {
            if (m_signaled) {
                m_signaled = false;
                return s_completed;
            }
            else {
                var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
                m_waits.Enqueue(tcs);
                return tcs.Task;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Set() {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> toRelease = null;
        lock (m_waits) {
            if (m_waits.Count > 0)
                toRelease = m_waits.Dequeue();
            else if (!m_signaled)
                m_signaled = true;
        }
        if (toRelease != null)
            toRelease.SetResult(true);
    }
}

It makes use of a queue internally (in a thread-safe way) which will satisfy our FIFO requirements. So the full example would be
LongJobWorker m_worker;
TaskFactory m_tfSyncContext;
readonly AsyncAutoResetEvent m_autoresetEvent;

public Presenter()
{
    m_worker = new LongJobWorker();
    m_tfSyncContext = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None,
                  TaskCreationOptions.None,
                  TaskContinuationOptions.None,
                  TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    m_autoresetEvent = new AsyncAutoResetEvent(true)
}

private async void worker_Event1(object sender, MyEventArgs e) {
    await _autoresetEvent.WaitAsync();
    try {
        await await _tfSyncContext.StartNew(new Func<Task>(() => worker_HandlerEvent1(e)));
    }
    finally {
        _autoresetEvent.Set();
    }
}

private async Task worker_HandlerEvent1(MyEventArgs e) {
    UpdateSomethingInUI(e.Value);

    // do something async like write a file
    await WriteSomethingOnFile(e.Value);
}

This is very similar to the answer by Theodor Zoulias which uses SemaphoreSlim. However, here we have full visibility of the FIFO nature of the implementation which is not very hard to reason about.
OLD ANSWER:
I think there is an even less pretty solution by using a BlockingCollection based producer-consumer queue (adapted from here)
public class PCQueue : IDisposable
{
    BlockingCollection<Func<Task>> _taskQ = new();
    private readonly TaskScheduler m_taskScheduler;
    private readonly TaskFactory _taskFactory;
    public PCQueue(TaskScheduler taskScheduler = null) {
        m_taskScheduler = taskScheduler ?? TaskScheduler.Default;

        _taskFactory = new TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None,
                TaskCreationOptions.None,
                TaskContinuationOptions.None,
                m_taskScheduler);
    }

    private bool _consuming = false;
    private readonly object _lockObj = new object();

    public void StartConsuming() {
        lock (_lockObj) {
            if (!_consuming) {
                _consuming = true;
                Task.Run(() => Consume());
            }
        }
    }

    public void EnqueueTask(Func<Task> action) => _taskQ.Add(action);

    async void Consume() {
        foreach (Func<Task> funcTask in _taskQ.GetConsumingEnumerable()) {
            var innerTask = await _taskFactory.StartNew(funcTask);
            await innerTask;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        _taskQ.CompleteAdding();
    }

}

Then
LongJobWorker m_worker;
public Presenter()
{
    m_worker = new LongJobWorker();
    m_pcQueue = new PCQueue(TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}

public void Start()
{
    m_worker.Event1 += worker_Event1;
    m_worker.Event2 += worker_Event2;
    m_pcQueue.StartConsuming();
    _ = Task.Run(async () => await m_worker.DoSomething());
}

    private void worker_Event1(object sender, MyEventArgs e) {
        _pcQueue.EnqueueTask(new Func<Task>(() => worker_HandlerEvent1(e)));
    }

    private async Task worker_HandlerEvent1(MyEventArgs e) {
        UpdateSomethingInUI(e.Value);

        // do something async like write a file
        await WriteSomethingOnFile(e.Value);
    }


I had been considering a similar solution since it seems to solve both the serialization and async void problems. The introduction of a new thread seemed like an overcomplication to me so before adopting it I wanted to understand if there are simpler alternatives. If not, I think I'll proceed like this.

@MaestroX check my new answer that refers to the implementation of AsyncAutoResetEvent by Stephen Toub (also read the blogpost for all context). I think it's transparent enough for you to have guarantees about serialization without tying up threads.

I'll show a possible solution that is neither pretty nor efficient, and also it doesn't offer a way to wait for all pending asynchronous operations before closing the window. Its only advantage is that it is easy to follow. It uses a SemaphoreSlim for disallowing concurrency, and a TaskScheduler tied to the captured SynchronizationContext, so that the event handlers are invoked on the UI thread:
public class Presenter
{
    private readonly LongJobWorker _worker;
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;
    private readonly TaskScheduler _scheduler;

    public Presenter()
    {
        _worker = new LongJobWorker();
        _semaphore = new(1, 1);
        _scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        _worker.Event1 += worker_Event1;
    }

    private async void worker_Event1(object sender, MyEventArgs e)
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
            {
                // update something in interface like put some text into a label
                UpdateSomethingInUI(e.Value);

                // do something async like write a file
                await WriteSomethingOnFile(e.Value);
            }, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, _scheduler).Unwrap();
        }
        finally { _semaphore.Release(); }
    }
}

It is assumed that the Presenter will be constructed on the UI thread, otherwise the TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext will not find any suitable SynchronizationContext to capture, and will throw an exception.
The SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync method is not documented to be FIFO, but you may find that its behavior is FIFO-enough for your needs.

My first attempt was something very similar but not exactly the same. Instead of declaring a semaphore in the Presenter I used the TaskQueue class described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25691679/best-way-in-net-to-manage-queue-of-tasks-on-a-separate-single-thread
Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in all cases, especially when the events are very close together.
The semaphore in fact guarantees that the events are managed in sequence but does not give certainty about the order and in fact sometimes the execution of the operations is not FIFO.

@MaestroX in a multithreaded environment the order is a loosely defined concept. The operating system can suspend any thread at any time for a duration of 10-30 milliseconds (demo), which messes up any strict definition of ordering.

In general I agree with you but in this application events are fired in a precise sequence and in that sequence I want to handle them.

@MaestroX if the events are fired as you are showing in the question (LongJobWorker.DoSomething method), they are fired sequentially, and the await _semaphore.WaitAsync(); should preserve their sequence. I would be very surprised if you observed out of order invocation of the handlers, even if you move the triggers as close together as possible by removing entirely the await Task.Delay between firing the events. Maybe you are firing them differently in your actual application?

@MaestroX I wrote a small experiment that demonstrates the behavior of the SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync. 100,000 tasks are created, and are suspended on a SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync. The semaphore is released once, so that the tasks can acquire the semaphore sequentially, the one after the other. Each task adds a sequential value in a list. Finally the list is compared for equality with the original sequence of values. The comparison shows that each SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync is acquired in the same order that it is created. That is what I expected to see.

I take a look to your experiment and the conclusion is that you are right (but only about order). My problem with order was due to a bug that now is fixed. Nevertheless there is another problem with this approach: since an "async void" method returns at the first "await", the operation inside the semaphore are not immediatly executed. The order, as you said, is guarantee but operations are not fired "as soon as possible". Do you have further advices?

@MaestroX the SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync task completes on the ThreadPool. Is the ThreadPool saturated? In case it is, you can buff it with the ThreadPool.SetMinThreads API.

ThreadPool is not saturated. Now I know what's the root cause of the problem. There are 2 handler registered for the same event. Both are async void because there is an await inside.
The event is fired but the control returns to the observed object when the await of the first handler is reached. Second handler will be managed later (I guess at the end of the firing method). Anyway too late for me.
Even if async void is "legal" for event, it is very painfull. Again, I'm looking for an alternative. Maybe I have to get rid of all the events and use an another pattern but it's a very big change.

@MaestroX you can avoid async void event handlers by exposing asynchronous events (public event Func<Task> XYZ). You can find an example here. It will be painful either way.

I think I'll try this solution but out of curiosity what should I do instead if the component that launches the events is third-party and therefore I'm not able to modify it?

@MaestroX I don't know. Is it an option to write a thin wrapper of the third-party component, that exposes asynchronous events?

I thought about it too but I came to the conclusion that inside the wrapper I would have a handler for the original event which would necessarily be async void with all the same problems.

@MaestroX the async void handler inside the wrapper could incorporate the SemaphoreSlim solution shown in this answer. At the end of the day you'll have to put the throttling code somewhere, either in the component itself, the wrapper or the client. You can't get away without it.
