# Ado.net calling Stored procedure from multi threading is slower than one thread

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading, ado.net

I'm trying to understand why when I use a single thread application 
with the following code

```
    public void Run(object state)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand("UpdatePriceInterval", connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;           
                for (int i = 0; i < 8000; i++)
                {
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

for the following code I'm getting a result of about 230 per second

Now if I try to do it with tasks (and of course change inside the loop to 80 iterations

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    list.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(Run, cancel, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
}
```

I'm getting a total result of about 3 second slower.(i'm running on localhsot i7)

I don't think to sp is the problem (as i deleted all the logic from it)

On SQL profiler i made sure the connection are pooled.

My task manager show everything is regular (cpu memory disk network) nothing is at 100%

What am I missing?

Comment: So the proc is empty? Then this should become a lot faster indeed. This is a remote server over the network, right?

Comment: Yes the proc is empty and I tried once on my local machine and once on a remote computer on the same network. the results were the same

Comment: So the proc is empty? Why does calling an empty proc on localhost take 5ms? That is far too much. Something is going on.

Comment: Just because you created a bunch of Tasks, they needn't run in different threads. Take a look at https://richnewman.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/why-starting-a-new-task-in-the-task-parallel-library-tpl-doesnt-always-start-a-new-thread/

Comment: You may also look into @usr answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138927/best-way-to-limit-the-number-of-active-tasks-running-via-the-parallel-task-libra

Comment: @Adarsha you are correct, however I did write the same code with new Thread(Run).Start(); I used Tasks has it give you better abstraction and i'd like to let .net handle exactly how much threads are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your "tasks" version is attempting to open many connections concurrently.

It will therefore likely create many more connections in the connection pool than the single-threaded version, which only needs to create a single connection in the connection pool.