# Maximum number of Threads available to Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, task, threadpool

I'm Trying to get my head around the async-await functionality within C#. I've written the below code to run several tasks asynchronously - currently all they do is raise an event after a certain amount of time.

```
public class Program
{
    public static Stopwatch Watch = new Stopwatch();

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsyncClass asyncClass = new AsyncClass();
        asyncClass.WaitSecondsAsyncCompleted += asyncClass_WaitSecondsAsyncCompleted;
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        Watch.Start();
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(asyncClass.WaitSecondsAsync(i, Watch));
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void asyncClass_WaitSecondsAsyncCompleted(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{1} : Async Method Called: waited for {0} seconds", i, Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}

public class AsyncClass
{
    public event Action<int> WaitSecondsAsyncCompleted;

    public async Task WaitSecondsAsync(int x, Stopwatch watch)
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {   
            Thread.Sleep(x * 500); 
        });

        if (WaitSecondsAsyncCompleted != null)
        {
            WaitSecondsAsyncCompleted(x);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd expect a task to be completed roughly once every half a second - however this is not quite what I see.  Instead the first four tasks complete on time but the final task has an extra half second delay:
[image: output of above code]

This seems very strange - and the only thing I can think of is that there is a limit on the number of threads that are available to a task and that this is limit is very small and so the fifth task is having to wait for the first task to complete before it can start.

I added some extra output and increased the number of tasks to try and gain more information but I can make little sense of it - the output seems to be deterministic, some threads are reused, but also new ones are used.  The delay on tasks being completed also seems to continue to grow (for instance for Task 10 I'd expect it to complete after 5 seconds, instead it stops after 8 seconds).  I've attached the output below.

What I'd like to know:

- Does anyone know what's going on in this particular example?
- Is the limit on threads available small enough to have an effect here?
- I presume asynchronous tasks are not guaranteed to start immediately, but there appears to be some other deterministic process going on here, which I hadn't expected.  Does anyone know what that is?

[image: output with extra debug info]

---

### Edit

Note that this question does not ask about the maximum number of tasks that can be run ([Max tasks in TPL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740495/max-tasks-in-tpl)) but rather how an effect can be seen when running as few as 5 tasks.  I was under the impression that default threadPool contained many more threads than this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Max tasks in TPL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740495/max-tasks-in-tpl)

Comment: Do you have four cores?

Comment: Yes it does have 4 cores - note from that second screen shot I posted that whilst initially it seems to be limited to 4 threads, that number later increases so that more tasks are running concurrently.

Comment: You might want to create separate stopwatches for each task, and add the displaying of the start-time. This will give you insight in when tasks are started as well.

Comment: And note that you are waiting for the tasks to finish with `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());` but you are not *awaiting* the tasks AFAIK.

Comment: Also, forget threads. They are just an implementation detail. Async actions can (sometimes) be run without any extra threads. Read [this article called 'There is no thread'](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

Comment: Thanks @Maarten - Just to clarify: I'm not awaiting them at the moment because this is just a very simple program and there wasn't really any need (also I naïvely thought that WaitAll awaited as well :) ).  The times that the individual tasks (inside the Task.Run) start is already recorded by the line starting "Inner Task Started", I don't think separate Stopwatches would add any clarity.

Comment: You wouldn't get this if you used `Task.Delay`  instead of `Thread.Sleep` (even if you wrap it in a task). `Thread.Sleep` will still block your threads

Comment: Thanks @AlexanderDerck  I noticed that, but though mentioning it would confuse the issue.  Thread.Sleep would better simulate a long running process that will block the thread.

Comment: @C.Knight The point of async operations is more that they don't need a thread though, what you simulate is parallel execution of code. For example while fetching data from a database you don't need a thread (while waiting on the database), *that* is when async comes into play.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So, it turns out that the issue I was seeing had to do with the threadpool size.  This is apparently initially set to the number of cores of the machine (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getminthreads%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It can be increased, and doing so means that more of the tasks are initially run simultaneously (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setminthreads%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I wanted to add that using `SetMaxThreads` to set the threadpool size is **not** recommended in most cases. This setting is per-process: other processes are not affected, but your entire application is.
Many TPL primitives (PLINQ, Parallel.*) allow you to set a max degree of parallelism.
Kudos to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12107981/3873799).