# .NET tasks are waiting on other tasks to finish before starting

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous

I have an async method that runs multiple tasks to convert Power BI reports to images, which is done in the cloud. The method executes about 60 of these tasks at once:

```
public async Task Func()
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task<string>>();
            var imgs = new List<ExportImageIdsDetail>();
            try
            {
                foreach (var eximg in db.ExportImageIdsDetails.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ToList())
                {
                    
                    // retrieve filters from db omitted 

                    imgs.Add(eximg);
                    var task = PowerBiTask(filters)
                    tasks.Add(task);
                }

                var exportIds = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                DateTime timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
                TimeZoneInfo easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
                DateTime udate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);
                for (var i = 0; i < exportIds.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exportIds[i]))
                    {
                        imgs[i].UpdatedDate = udate;
                        imgs[i].ExportImageId = exportIds[i];
                    }
                }
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

When I run the program, sometimes all of the tasks run at the same time, but there are times where about 50 of the tasks run at once, then the rest of the tasks seem to run synchronously (e.g. task 51 runs for 30 seconds, then task 52 runs for 30 seconds...). Why does this happen? Is there any way to ensure that all tasks run at once? Task Manager was showing that memory and cpu were only at 50% load as well.

Answer (score 0):

To fully answer your question you'll need to provide the implementation of `PowerBiTask(filters)`. But from what I can see I suggest reading this: [Maximum number of Threads available to Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39222981/maximum-number-of-threads-available-to-tasks).

The thread pool size is set to the number of physical cores on the machine initially, if you do a lot of computational work increasing this might give you a higher degree of parallelism.

Important to note: **do measurements**, synchronous execution might be faster than using more parallelism in some cases.

Comment: Thanks, `PowerBiTask` calls another method to export the report to an image, then the status of the export is polled every few seconds until success or timeout/error. Hope this helps

Comment: I believe the issue was that `PowerBiTask` was using `Thread.Sleep()` for the polling interval. I replaced this with `await Task.Delay()` and everything is much faster

Comment: Thread.Sleep blocks the thread meaning it can't be used to do any processing on other tasks, Task.Delay suspends it which allows it to process another task while it's waiting :) Glad you figured it out